# celery - how to conceal the logging of arguments

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, flower

I have the following celery task:

```
@pp.task(name="my dummy task")
def dummy_task(args, my_ids):
    print ("run background task")
    //long process here
    return {'status':'ok}
```

The thing is that the my_ids carries a lot of information and when I look at '[flower](https://github.com/mher/flower)' app the args column is completely cluttered. Is there any annotation/decorator to use to avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure `format-task` which is flower's [configuration](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#format-task):

> Modifies the default task formatting. format_task function should be
> defined in the flowerconfig.py configuration file. It accepts a task
> object and returns the modified version.
>
> format_task is useful for filtering out sensitive information.

The example in the link shows you how to limit display lengths (or filter the `my_ids` out).

Comment: @ProcolHarum did you try it?